# Edit and read OneDrive file with microsoft graph

Tags: javascript, graph, onedrive

I‘m want to look and edit a onedrive file where I have the share link to. I found microsoft graph, but there I only can access to my files. Is it possible to look/edit this files where I have the link without a login? I do everything with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Add permission using azure ad

1. edit
2. user.read

app->>api permission->>add a permission->>microsoftgraph->>select the permission->>add

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more?